# Avoiding duplication of code for jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, function

I have this script (one of my first) which I have had a bit of help developing:
http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/AYUmk/2/

```
var addButton =$("#add"),
    newResp = $("#resp_input"),
    respTextArea = $("#responsibilities"),
    respList = $("#resp");

//
function Responsibility(text){
    this.text=text;
}
var responsibilities = []; 

function render(){
    respList.html("");
    $.each(responsibilities,function(i,responsibility){
        var el = renderResponsibility(responsibilities[i],function(){
            responsibilities.splice(i,1);//remove the element
            render();//re-render
        });
        respList.append(el);
    });
    respTextArea.text(responsibilities.map(function(elem){
       return elem.text;//get the text. 
    }).join("\n"));
}

addButton.click(function(e){
    var resp = new Responsibility(newResp.val());
    responsibilities.push(resp);
    render();
    newResp.val("");
});

function renderResponsibility(rep,deleteClick){
    var el = $("<li>");
    var rem = $("<a>Remove</a>").click(deleteClick);
    var cont = $("<span>").text(rep.text+" ");
    return el.append(cont).append(rem);
}
```

Using the top box you can add responsibilities into the text area by typing them into the input box and clicking add. This works perfectly for my first box, but I need this to work for three different boxes and now I'm getting a bit stuck on how to apply this function to all three instances "responsibility, test, test2" without simply duplicating the code three times and changing the variables.

I'm sure this type of thing must come up a lot but I'm not sure if it can be avoid. Hopefully someone with more javascript experience can shed some light on this.

Comment: so, don't use IDs, use class instead.

Comment: Ok, that is a good suggestion, but how do I avoid the script putting the list in the correct input box. I.e test2 into test2

Comment: first, you should wrap each block inside a container (div), then targetting correct elements will be very easy like: $(this).closest('.container').find('.responsibilities'), etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. use the scoping of javascript for this:

```
function Responsibility(text){
    /* .... */
}

function setUp(addButton, newResp, respTextArea, respList) {


    var responsibilities = []; 

    function render(){
        /* ..... */
    }

    addButton.click(function(e){
        /* ..... */
    });

    function renderResponsibility(rep,deleteClick){
        /* ..... */
    }
}
```

And then for each group you can call:

```
setUp($("#add"), $("#resp_input"), $("#responsibilities"), $("#resp") );
```

You need for sure have either different `id` for each of this fields like `#add1`, `#add2` ...
or you could also group each of this into e.g. a `div` with a class like `.group1`  and use `class` instead of `id` like `.add` , `.resp_input` then you even could reduce the number of parameters you need to pass to the setup to one paramter (only passing the container)

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to do exactly what you want.

**Live Demo http://jsfiddle.net/AYUmk/5/**

---

The trick is to make your `responsibilities` array a multidimensional array that holds an array for each item (in this case, 3 items).

```
var responsibilities = [new Array(),new Array(),new Array()];
```

Then, I updated the add buttons to have a CLASS of `add` instead of an ID of `add`. You should never have more than one element with the same ID anyway. Additionally, I added several data items to the buttons. These data items tell the jQuery which array item to use, which textbox to look for, which list to add to, and which text box to add to.

```
<input type="button" value="Add" class="add" data-destination='responsibilities' data-source='resp_input' data-list='resp' data-index="0">
...
<input type="button" value="Add" class="add" data-destination='test' data-source='tst_input' data-list='tst' data-index="1">
...
<input type="button" value="Add" class="add" data-destination='test2' data-source='tst2_input' data-list='tst2' data-index="2">
```

Then it was just a matter of changing your `click()` and `render()` functions to handle the data and multidimensional array

```
function render(list, textarea, index){
    list.html("");
    $.each(responsibilities[index],function(i,responsibility){
        var el = renderResponsibility(responsibilities[index][i],function(){
            responsibilities[index].splice(i,1);//remove the element
            render();//re-render
        });
        list.append(el);
    });
    textarea.text(responsibilities[index].map(function(elem){
       return elem.text;//get the text. 
    }).join("\n"));
}

$('.add').click(function(e){
    var source = $('#' + $(this).data('source') ).val();
    var index = parseInt($(this).data('index'));
    var list = $('#' + $(this).data('list') );
    var dest = $('#' + $(this).data('destination') );
    var resp = new Responsibility(source);    
    responsibilities[index].push(resp);
    render(list, dest, index);
    newResp.val("");
});
```

**NOTE: I did not get the removal working, let me know if you require assistance with that as well and I will assist once I reach my office**

Comment: You're right, but I find this to be a funny critique coming from someone whose answer duplicates list items and ends with "but i wont do the whole worke for you :)"

Comment: just saying :P ... my answer is more a hint then a solution ;)

Comment: Hi @Dutchie432, thank you for your help and explaining this. I would appreciate information about getting delete working since I can't get away from the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined error when removing

Comment: There is also a few errors when you try to add items to the second two lists, it doesnt clear the field when you add an item

Comment: Frankly there are a few errors, I suppose - I sort of just got it working enough. I am running out the door to work - I will expand on the code once I get there. Sorry for delaying.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this > http://jsfiddle.net/AYUmk/4/

I would access the items by class instead of ids

```
$(".class").find("...");
```

you just need to outscource responsibilities = []; and then it works perfect...

but i wont do the whole worke for you :)